# Passing properties from DropzoneArea to Dropzone

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-dropzone

I am using `DropzoneArea`:

```
import { DropzoneArea } from 'material-ui-dropzone';
```

which is based on `react-dropzone`.

`Dropzone` from:

```
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone'
```

contains certain props, not exposed by `DropzoneArea` but available by [Dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org/)

For instance `disabled`.

I have several question regarding it:
When I create `DropzoneArea` component, is there a way to mark it as disabled?
Is there a way to pass original properties of `Dropzone`

And here is an original issue I try to solve, probably the solution is not the best one and there are alternatives:
When a user uploads a file to DropzoneArea, I can send it to the server via `onChange` handler. I'd like to disable the whole component, while server is processing a file, until we get a response back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DropzoneArea has the property `dropzoneProps`, which is an object that is being passed (as props) to the Dropzone:

```
<DropzoneArea
    dropzoneProps={ { disabled: true} }
    ...
/>
```